# How to leverage browser cache globally on Easyapache4?

Tags: apache, caching, httpd.conf, easyapache-4

[This article](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-configure-apache-2-to-control-browser-caching/) explains how to configure Apache2 with directives in either .htaccess or in httpd.conf to work globally. However in EasyApache4 httpd.conf is automatically generated, it says that modifications should go in include files, and it lists the following three files:

> /etc/apache2/conf.d/includes/pre_main_global.conf
>   /etc/apache2/conf.d/includes/pre_virtualhost_global.conf
>   /etc/apache2/conf.d/includes/post_virtualhost_global.conf

[This article](http://linuxpitstop.com/configure-apache-mod_expires-on-file-extensions/) talks about creating a new file expire.conf file in /etc/apache2/conf.d/ (ie not adding directives to an existing file and not in the includes sub-directory). [This article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-apache-content-caching-on-centos-7) talks about creating a new file 00-cache.conf in the conf.modules.d directory.

I'm confused whether to add directives to an existing file in the includes sub-directory, and if so which one, or to create a new file, and if so what filename to use and where to put it.

Can anyone advise please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking into the same thing, and it's becoming clear that when on EA4, you should simply follow EA4 structures - the 3 include files you're already listing.

`pre_virtualhost_global.conf` is probably the most appropriate spot.